# Let b denote a fixed positive integer, for every integer $n≥0$ there exist nonnegative integers q and r such that $n=qb+r|0≤r<b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

> Let b denote a fixed positive integer, for every integer $n≥0$ there
> exist nonnegative integers q and r such that $n=qb+r$$,0≤r<b$

So I'm trying to solve it with induction, the same way I have with other problems of my book :

- $A(0):0=0b+0$
- $A(1):1=0b+1$

...

- $A(k):k=qb+r$

now I evaluate for k+1

- $A(k+1):k+1=qb+r$

  $A(k)+1:k+1=qb+r+1$

So, at this point, I try to do, as I do with other proofs by induction, and try to prove:

$qb+r=qb+r+1$

but as you can see, this makes no sense, because $qb+r<qb+r+1$, so, I think I might be doing it the wrong way. Could you help me with this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: start by letting $q$ be the largest integer such that $qb \le n$. (You may need to use some preliminary results to know there is such an integer, or you may be able to assert it without proof - that depends on the level and kind of rigor your course demands).

Answer (score 1):

Step:

$n+ 1 = qb + r+1 ; $

1) If $ r+1 <b $; take

$r'=r+1$ , $q,b$, as before.

2) If $r+1 = b,$ consider

$n+1 = qb +( r+1) = qb +b =(q+1)b;$

$n+1 = q'b +r'$ ,

$q'=q+1$, and $r' = 0$ .

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that for $k+1$ there exist *some* $q$ and $r$ such that $$k+1=qb+r$$ ... these $q$ and $r$ need not (in fact, as you found out, they *cannot*!) be the same $q$ and $r$ for which $$k=qb+r$$

So, if we assume

$$k=qb+r$$

then what we're looking for is some $q'$ and $r'$ such that:

$$k+1=q'b+r'$$

Now, while not the same as $q$ and $r$, $q'$ and $r'$ are nevertheless closely related to $q$ and $r$ ... can you see how?

HINT:

separate the case where $r=b-1$ from the case where $0 \le r < b-1$ (also treat $b=1$ as a special case)